# Derby java -derbyrun.jar server to change embedded mode to server mode

Tags: java, environment-variables, derby, javadb, linux-mint

I have derby DB working fine in embedded  mode through  my netbeans IDE as am
developing accounting multi-user systems ,it's my first time with Derby and understood later embedded
mode not allowing multi users/pcs, only single user, so i decided to move my Derby
into server mode and am trying for days changing environment variable to convert to server mode ,and change my embeded one into server one is possible or i have to drop the derby and install server mode  ,now am attempting to run derbyrun.jar from my Linux terminal  but  i have got below error message .
wso here i can put the jar file to avoid seen below error :

java -jar derbyrun.jar server start
Error: Unable to access jarfile derbyrun.jar
any help will be great

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you start derby in network server mode and still get an embedded connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374833/how-do-you-start-derby-in-network-server-mode-and-still-get-an-embedded-connecti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like derbyrun.jar is not in your classpath.

I suggest you take a couple hours and work through the Derby Getting Started guide here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/

In particular, there is an example in that manual of taking a Derby application which runs with the embedded driver, and converting that application to use the client driver: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/twwdactivity4.html

In general, all you have to do is to change your connection URL, include derbyclient.jar in your classpath, and have a running Derby Network Server that is providing access to your database.

To run the Derby Network Server, you should start with the startup scripts that are provided in the Derby distribution; this, too, is covered in the Getting Started guide.

Comment: yes looks i need to learn setting up environment variables further more

Comment: yes looks   an environment variables prob, i have the derbyrun.jar showing in  /home/mohamed/glassfish-4.0/javadb/lib/derbyrun.jar     where i can copy this jar to be able to add it to classpath because unable to know even through reading many stuff here and there perhaps unable to udnerstand where i can get the classpath and how to advise to OS linux i mean about it

Comment: To control your classpath, you just have to set the CLASSPATH environment variable, or use the -cp argument to the java launcher. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html