# Derby access in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, derby

I'm trying to learn the basics of database access, and I chose to use `Derby`. I'm using `Embedder Derby`, and I have `IntelliJ` set up so that it connects to `Derby`. However, when `IntelliJ` is connected to the database, my applications cannot access it. I know that I have to disconnect from the database from `IntelliJ` before attempting to access it with my application. Is there a way to set it up so that I can access the database with both `IntelliJ` and my application at the same time?

Comment: @TarlanMammadzada you may want to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165700/abuse-of-code-formatting-to-add-unnecessary-emphasis before making additional edits.

Comment: @trooper Good, thanks

Comment: a shot in the dark, but you may be able to access it from both simultaneously using "embedded server mode". Once you have embedded mode working, getting "embedded server mode" is a quick step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374833/how-do-you-start-derby-in-network-server-mode-and-still-get-an-embedded-connecti/22641222#22641222

Comment: Use the Derby Network Server, and switch from the `EmbeddedDriver` to the `ClientDriver` in your JDBC Connection configuration. Then multiple applications can access the database at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the Embedded Database from more than one process, because when you run the Apache Derby database in embedded mode, only one Java process is created. The database process becomes an integral part of the process in which it was created.

[image: Derby embedded architecture]

However, you can use client/server mode to access the database with more than one application.