# Turning derby embedded database into derby network datatbase

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

Hi I learned programming by myself so please excuse me if I ask any dumb questions. I have developed a hotel management system and before finishing it I stumbled upon a confused task. I was using derby embedded database for my application as I was thinking for a single user application. But when i got my application really bigger I want this embedded data base in my main application to be accessible to few other application from different machines(basically application is same but with different user configuration). I was thinking to install an external database like Oracle or mySQL and being accessible by all application. But I came to know about this derby network server and I have few questions

1. Can I turn my main application as the server allowing other client applications accessible to it's embedded database ?
2. If answer to first question is yes then where I should make changes ? I already have jar files like derbynet.jar in my project.What changes should I make from embedded to network database ?

I just started learning JSP/Servelts so I wont be able to follow anything if you suggest to use this architecture.

**UPDATE:-**
I found some useful answers and realized that its possible to make my embedded derby a network database. But my problem now is how to start the network server and open the port.
I added below codes to my connection statements when my application starts.

```
"CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(\n"
            + "    'derby.drda.startNetworkServer', 'true')";

"CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(\n"
            + "    'derby.drda.portNumber', '8011')"
```

and I executed this with my statements. Though it did not give any errors the `netstat -an` did not show me the port. And also my client application is not able to connect. I am getting "error connecting to server 0.0.0.0 on port: 8011 connection refused"
I think this is not the way to start the network server or opening the port.
Can anyone help me how to do this ?

Comment: its called "embedded server mode". if you are already using embedded mode successfully, you can turn on server mode w/ a command line option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374833/how-do-you-start-derby-in-network-server-mode-and-still-get-an-embedded-connecti/22641222#22641222

Comment: Regarding your updated question: is it port 1081, or port 8011? Your question mentions both.

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton, sorry that was a type mistake. I corrected. thank you